# SQL: How to parse a column delimited with semicolon?

Tags: sql, oracle, delimiter

How can I parse a column where data is delimited with semicolon ?

INPUT

```
+ Column1                              +
+--------------------------------------+
+ param1=valA;param2=valB;             +
+ param1=valX;param2=valY;param3=valZ; +
```

OUTPUT of the select

```
valA, valB, null
valX, valY, valZ
```

Thanks,

Comment: You might do well to try to normalize your data before loading it into the database, e.g. placing each delimited assignment term into a separate column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want three columns, you may want three `regexp_substr()`:

```
select replace(regexp_substr(col1, 'param1=[^;]*'), 'param1=', '') as param1,
       replace(regexp_substr(col1, 'param2=[^;]*'), 'param2=', '') as param2,
       replace(regexp_substr(col1, 'param3=[^;]*'), 'param3=', '') as param3
```